# Image Preloader Getting Stuck in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, internet-explorer-8, preloader

I've searched high and low for a solution to this problem, extremely grateful to anyone who can shed some light.

Below is a simplified version of a function used to preload 25 images. It works fantastically well in IE9-10 and in Chrome.

In IE8 it gets partway through loading the images (e.g. 10/25) then just stops. If I then refresh the browser it will continue to load images, taking ~3 refreshes to complete. This should not be necessary!

On the odd occasion it does succeed in loading all images in one go. I tried to avoid using .load() as I've read it can be problematic in IE yet here I am just the same! I also tried using different images to rule out the image format as the cause.

I'm looking for either a fix to the below code or a better solution if someone has one.

Many thanks.

```
function loadAllImages() {
    var imgArray = [ //image SRCs stored in array
    'imgsrc01.jpg',
    'imgsrc02.jpg',
    'imgsrc03.jpg',
    ...
    'imgsrc25.jpg'];

    var noFinalImg = imgArray.length - 1; 
    var i = -1;
    var waitTime = 10000;

    if (imgArray.length === 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        loadImage();
    };

    function loadImage() {
        i++;
        var url = imgArray[i];
        var img = new Image();
        var timer;

        img.src = url;
        img.id = "thumb" + i;

        // image loaded
        if (img.complete || img.readyState === 4) {
                    //Call image loaded function
                    console.log(i + "/" + noFinalImg);

            //equivalent to loop next
            if (i !== noFinalImg) {
                loadImage();
            };
            // image not loaded
        } else {
            // handle 404 using setTimeout set at waitTime
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                if (i !== noFinalImg) {
                    loadImage();
                };
                $(img).unbind('error load onreadystate');
            }, waitTime);
            $(img).bind('error load onreadystatechange', function (e) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                if (e.type !== 'error') {
                    //Call image loaded function
                    console.log(i + "/" + noFinalImg);

                };
                if (i !== noFinalImg) {
                    loadImage();
                };
            });
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: don't set the src until after you've bound the events to the img element. By doing so, you can skip the complete/readystate check and rely on load being consistent in all browsers.

Comment: You should also consider caching each img object you create in a global variable instead of leaving it as a function variable which could be garbage collected causing all of the in-flight downloads to be aborted.

Comment: Great! Setting the src after the if statement which binds events (either after the entire if statement or at the beginning of each logical branch) loads all images successfully in all browsers! However, an unwanted 'side-effect' of this is that in my subsequent `imageLoaded()` function, `$(img).width()` returns 0 instead of the actual width in Chrome (not a problem in IE). I'll look for a solution to this (perhaps by setting the src in different areas of my `loadimage()` function according to the browser version).

I'm also now caching the img objects to a second array.

Thanks very much!

Comment: After more testing, I've found that by setting the src both before binding events to the img element and after that, I am able to solve all problems in these browsers! It doesn't make for the absolutely cleanest code ever written but produces the desired result. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.